# Django - Access to ForeignKey in template, but with a filter

Tags: django, foreign-key-relationship

I need to access a foreignkey of a list of objects but i can't make it work.

This are my models

```
class Subcategory(models.Model):
# Relations

# Attributes - Mandatory
name = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        verbose_name=_('name'),
    )

class Product(models.Model):
    # Attributes - Mandatory
    name = models.CharField(
            max_length=63,
            unique=True,
            verbose_name=_('name'),
        )
    slug = models.SlugField(
            max_length=63,
            unique=True,
            editable=False,
            verbose_name=_('slug'),
        )
    title = models.CharField(
            max_length=63,
            editable=False,
            help_text=_('name to show the product in the templates'),
            verbose_name=_('title')
        )
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(
            Subcategory,
            verbose_name=_('subcategory'),
        )
    # Precio de venta al público
    sell_price = models.DecimalField(
            max_digits=10,
            decimal_places=2,
            verbose_name=_('sell price'),
        )

    minimal_quantity = models.SmallIntegerField(
            default=1,
            verbose_name=_('minimal quantity'),
        )
    available = models.BooleanField(
            default=True,
        )
    created = models.DateTimeField(
            editable=False,
            verbose_name=_('created'),
        )
    modified = models.DateTimeField(
            editable=False,
            verbose_name=_('modified'),
        )
```

And i have to access to the Stock of the products

```
class ProductStock(models.Model):
    # Relations
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product,
        verbose_name=_('product'),
    )
    warehouse = models.ForeignKey(
        Warehouse,
        default = 1,
        verbose_name=_('warehouse'),
    )
    # Attributes - Mandatory
    quantity = models.IntegerField(
        verbose_name=_('quantity'),
    )
```

this is the Warehouse model, it's in other app

```
class Warehouse(models.Model):
    # Relations
    store = models.ForeignKey(
            Store,
            blank=True,
            null=True,
            related_name='warehouse',
            verbose_name=_('store'),
        )

    # Attributes - Mandatory
    name = models.CharField(
            max_length=50,
            verbose_name=_('name'),
        )

    # Attributes - Optional
    address = models.CharField(
            max_length=100,
            verbose_name=_('address'),
        )
    phone = models.CharField(
            max_length=50,
            verbose_name=_('phone'),
        )

    # Attributes - Optional
    phone2 = models.CharField(
            max_length=50,
            blank=True,
            null=True,
            verbose_name=_('phone 2'),
        )
    mail = models.EmailField(
            verbose_name=_('mail'),
        )
```

This is my function view

```
def product_stock_list(request, subcategory_id=None):
subcategory = None
subcategories = Subcategory.objects.all().order_by('family', 'name')
products = Product.objects.filter(available=True).exclude(subcategory=1)
if subcategory_id:
    subcategory = get_object_or_404(Subcategory, id=subcategory_id)
    products = products.filter(subcategory=subcategory)
if request.GET:
    try:
        ean13 = request.GET.get('ean13')
        ean13 = ean13.upper()
        p = products.get(ean13=ean13)
        return redirect(reverse('products:detail', kwargs=({'id': p.id, 'slug': p.slug})))
    except:

        products = None

return render(
        request,
        'products/stock_list.html',
        {
        'subcategory': subcategory,
        'subcategories': subcategories,
        'products': products,
        }
    )
```

Well the quantity of a list products that i'm trying to get is the product quantity on the Warehouse with ID=1 only that.

I need precisely this:
Produc1 - Quantity
Product2 - Quantity
Product3 - Quantity
...
...
ProductN - Quantity

Thanks for your help!

Comment: provide your warehouse model !

Comment: Already added to the post!! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a better way, but the way I do it is first get the warehouse object

```
warehouse_1=Warehouse.objects.get(id=1)
```

and now get the `quantity` from `ProductStock`

```
products=ProductStock.objects.filter(warehouse=warehouse_1)
```

Then you can loop through this resulting query set to get what you want

```
for product in products:
    if product.subcategory.id != '10':
        print str(product.product.name) + " " + str(product.quantity)
```

Does that work?

Comment: Thanks! i'm going to try now and let you know if i make it work!

Comment: OK. Please let me know. Thansk.

Comment: I seem to explain myself wrong, when I tried this I realized that what I need is the stock of a list of products. i add the view in the original post

Comment: I don't see `stock` as a field in any of your models.

Comment: Sorry i need to show the quantity of the warehouse 1 for each product in the list

Comment: OK. I edited my answer, but I didn't test my work, so please let me know how it goes.

Comment: Excellent, that work!!! can i borther you with one more thing. Can you imagine how to do a small filter in the product. i need to exclude of the list the products with the "subcategory" ID=10 (i don't put the category, subcategory, etc in the model to make it smaller in the post but the product have that attribute). When i use the product model i make the exclude in the query but now i don't know how to make this because we use the ProductStock model.

Comment: I actually think it may be as simple as `products=ProductStock.objects.filter(warehouse=warehouse_1).exclude(id=10)` if I get what you're asking.

Comment: I'm going to try but i thing that this code exclude the product registered in the productstock table with the ID 10, i need to exclude all the products that have the SubCategory 10 in the Product Model i edit the product model to make it easy to see

Comment: Can I see your `Subcategory` model?

Comment: Yes!!! of course i added to the principal post!!! but is very simple only the name of the subcategory

Comment: I still don't see it.

Comment: OK. I modified my code slightly with an `if-statement` in the `loop`. I think it'll work, though the `name` field is a `CharField` so I am not sure if `10` is what you really want there. Please have a look.

Comment: is the Subcategory_id=10 but i go to try editing your code!!! let you know in a few minutes. Thanks!!!

Comment: OK, yes, try `product.subcategory.id != 10` instead.

Comment: Exactly i just enter here to post the same that you put here!!! Thanks very much for all your help!!!! The code is already working!!!